# HSQLDB - bitwise operation method BITANDNOT() is not found

Tags: java, hsqldb, bitwise-operators

I am new to hsqldb. I am getting below error on calling BITANDNOT() function.

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: BITANDNOT
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readColumnOrFunctionExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
```

I am passing simply two values in this function call say for example

```
BITANDNOT(field1, val1)
Here,
field1 is field in table
val1 is string value of an Integer object
```

I am kind of stuck with this exception. Please help if anyone have experience with hsqldb.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/builtinfunctions-chapt.html#bfc_numeric_functions

Comment: It works for me. And you are sure you are using V2.3?  What is the *exact* statement you are running?

Comment: I am using version 2.2.4

Comment: The 2.2 manual does not contain that function, so I guess you need to upgrade to 2.3

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your help. It was introduced in 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Bitwise operating functions were introduced in v2.2.6.

If you are not able to cop up with 2.3 then get 2.2.9. It worked for me.